# Force client side validation of a certain attribute conditionally

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form, client-side-validation

I am using this client side validation library: https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations together with simple form to render forms in rails 3.2.12.

I have a model with two attributes, `cancelled:bool` and `cancelled_reason:string`. When `cancelled` is set I would like to force the reason to be set as well, I do this with a simple validation:

```
validates :cancelled_reason, presence: true, if: "cancelled"
```

I then have a form that contains a hidden input for `cancelled = true` and a text field for `cancelled_reason`. What I would like to do is a) render this field as if it had presence: true (with the 'required star' next to it) and b) make the client side validation work properly for this field.

I have attempted several things to make this happen, following the documentation of client side validation.

```
<%= f.input :cancelled_reason, validate: true do %>

<%= f.input :cancelled_reason, validate: { presence: true } do %>

<%= f.input :cancelled_reason do %>
    <% f.text_field :cancelled_reason, validate: { presence: true } %>
<% end %>
```

All these still results in an empty 'validation' array in the javascript for the form, so it can be submitted anyways. It also fails on rendering the field as I required field.

I also attempted to manually set the 'cancelled' field to true before rendering the form, this did not work properly either.

```
<% model.cancelled = true %>
<% simple_form_for @model, validate: true do |f| %>
    ...
<% end %>
```

Any idea on how to make this work?

Comment: Is `model` the same as `@model` in your example?  I asked because I wouldn't expect `model.cancelled = true` to work unless `model === @model`

Comment: Also, see my suggestions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22906257/client-side-validation-is-not-working-while-applying-conditional-validation-in-r/22943098#22943098)