# Client side validation is not working while applying conditional validation in rails 4

Tags: validation, client-side

I am using client side validation gem. Client side validation is not working while applying conditions.
Here is my Model Class.

```
validates_uniqueness_of :project_code
**validates :price, numericality: true, :if => :project_type_fixed?**

def project_type_fixed?
  project_type == 'Fixed'
end
```

In this code validation for `project_code` is working fine, but for `price` it is not working.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Client_side_validations does not validate conditionals out-of-the-box.  What you are observing is the intended behavior.

In order to validate conditionals, you need to force them in your form:

```
f.number_field :price, :validate => { :numericality => true}
```

In addition, according to [the documentation](https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations#conditional-validators), the value needs to evaluate to true at the time the form is being generated.  However, there is a hack for this:  The method that determines whether the condition evaluates to true is called  `run_conditional` ([source](https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations/blob/3-2-stable/lib/client_side_validations/active_model.rb#L89)), so you can override that method in your model:

```
def run_conditional(method_name_value_or_proc)
  (:project_type_fixed? == method_name_value_or_proc) || super
end
```